# How to convert "None" to null in DRF custom exception?

Tags: python, django, exception, django-rest-framework

I'm currently learning Django Rest Framework and currently stuck on a problem which is kind of impossible for me to figure out.
I'm providing you an example, just to make the picture clearer.

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission



class CheckAuthentication(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        authenticated = request.auth

        if not authenticated:
            
            raise PermissionDenied(
            {
                "exception_data": None
            }
        )
        return True
```

Ok So, in the above example I want to response to be like the following JSON

```
{
    "exception_data": null
}
```

but instead of it, I'm getting

```
{
    "exception_data": "None"
}
```

is there any way I can get the desired JSON ??

Comment: `null` is not a Python constant.

Comment: @Prune I know that, but whenever we return None as a value in response JSON it is always coverted to null, since it is correspondence of None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done via custom exception handling

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler


def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    if response is not None:
            exception_data = str(exc.detail['exception_data'])
            response.data['exception_data'] = None if exception_data == "None" else exception_data

    return response
```

and then in your settings.py you have to mention the custom_exception_handler, like the following

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'my_project.my_app.utils.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json` package, for ex:

```
>>> import json
>>> d = {'t':None}
>>> json.dumps(d)
'{"t": null}'
```